# How to set up ssl for an nginx docker

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I was following this tutorial https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-a-private-docker-registry on setting up a private registry with self-signed certificates. However, I am lost at step 6, the ssl bit. How do I create and add the Root CA Certificate? BTW my /etc/docker/ folder doesn't have certs.d folder.

Comment: `mkdir -p` is short for `mkdir --parents` meaning in this case "Create all the folders in the path, not just the final one". After running this command it should create both the missing `certs.d` directory and the `registry.example-server.com` one inside it.

Comment: You mention using a self-signed cert suggesting that you want TLS but you're not looking to secure this as a private registry on the public network, correct? If so, you may find it easier to use a simpler process, see: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates. You still need to follow @omer-tuchfeld's advice above to create the directory.

Comment: It is actually a private network. I would like to host my registry.  when I try to login I get the error:   certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match registry.com